# Batch files - Loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I just need some help making a looping copying of files in my directory to multiple different computers. Because my usual code is just like this:

```
copy C:\file.txt \\destination\c$\destinationFolder\
copy C:\file.txt \\destination\c$\destinationFolder\
copy C:\file.txt \\destination\c$\destinationFolder\
copy C:\file.txt \\destination\c$\destinationFolder\
```

I dont really understand how to make this a looping batch file. Where I will have a list of computers in a .txt file and the script will call it there and copy to the destination file as it loops till its done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%G IN (\\destination\c$\destinationFolder\, \\destination2\c$\destinationFolder\) DO (
  ECHO %%G
  copy C:\file.txt %%G
)
```

Didn't tested the Copy part, but it is echoing the paths

Comment: so this is what i try now...

    '@echo off

    set comp=c:\comp.txt

    if exist %comp% goto label1
    echo.
    echo cannot find %comp%
    echo.
    pause

    goto :eof
    pause

    :label1
    FOR %%G IN (%comp%) DO (  ECHO %%G
    copy\\%comp%\c$\destinationfolder %%G)'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example will be of use to you.

```
for %%d in (
    "\\destination1\share\destinationFolder\"
    "\\destination2\share\destinationFolder\"
    "\\destination3\share\destinationFolder\"
    "\\destination4\share\destinationFolder\"
) do (
    copy "c:\file.txt" "%~d"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that your list of files is in a text file... luckily the FOR command can also iterate over the lines of a text file.

Assuming your text file (computers.txt) looks like this:

```
\\destination1\c$\destinationFolder
\\destination2\c$\destinationFolder
... etc.
```

You can iterate over the lines like so:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%Q IN (computers.txt) DO (
  COPY C:\file.txt %%Q
)
```

Each line in the input file is put into the %%Q variable and the COPY command is executed for each.